# Lifetime of a temporary with temporary subexpressions, bound to a reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

Is the following use of `p` within `main` safe? I believe binding the temporary produced by `mk_pair` has its lifetime extended to that of `p`, but how about the temporary objects created by `Wrap{1}` and `Wrap{2}`?

```
struct Wrap { int &&x; };

struct Pair { Wrap &&w1, &&w2; };

Pair mk_pair(Wrap &&w1, Wrap &&w2) { return Pair{std::move(w1),std::move(w2)}; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Pair &&p = mk_pair(Wrap{1},Wrap{2});
  std::cout << p.w1.x << ' ' << p.w2.x << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. `Wrap{1}` and `Wrap{2}` are not bound to automatic references in `main`, so they are destructed at the end of the line.

The `Pair` returned from `mk_pair` has its lifetime extended to that of `p`, but its references are dangling.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior.  In

```
mk_pair(Wrap &&w1, Wrap &&w2)
```

you take `w1` and `w2` as rvalue references, which is okay, you extend the life into the function.  Then you return an object that refers to those references.  The problem with that is when the expression ends, those temporaries you passed by reference, are destroyed.  That means you know have references to refer to expired objects and using those is undefined behavior.